# Unexpected multiplication behavior

Tags: javascript, typescript, babeljs, v8

Can anyone explain what makes this valid? String in an array multiplied yields the result like the array or string never mattered.

#### equation

`["155"] * 100 = 15500`

Comment: Are you asking why it is doing that, or are you asking why jsfiddle is different?

Comment: @CertainPerformance https://jsfiddle.net/rxz4v2cn/
macosx 10.15.3 and chrome 84.0.4147.135 if it matters

Comment: @Taplar why it's doing that and what could be causing it. The inner workings of js are always intriguing to me. Even CertainPerformance getting a different result in jsfiddle is interesting

Comment: Umm ... `c = ["100"] * 10000;` ..?

Comment: Thanks, but it looks like you have `const c = ["100"] * 10000;` there - you aren't multiplying the `["166"]`

Comment: @CertainPerformance ohhhh well, i screwed up the fiddle, sorry I'm going to edit the question then to what i wondered what it was originally doing. Why a string in an array was being multiplied directly

Comment: @CertainPerformance Thanks, that's interesting. If you want the credit post as an answer. I knew about the result of string concatenation stuff like `'44' + 100` and number coercing like `'44' * 100` but never knew why and never  thought it would go so far as arrays. Not my code, just something interesting i was curious about.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When a non-numeric value is operated on with something that only makes sense for numeric values - like `*` or `/` or `%` - JS attempts to coerce the non-numeric value into a numeric value. `Number(['155'])` turns into `155`. It's weird, but legal. Usually, if you see code which relies on something like that, it's bad code that deserves refactoring.

This behavior is described in the specification [here](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-applystringornumericbinaryoperator), ApplyStringOrNumericBinaryOperator:

> 3. Let lnum be ? ToNumeric(lval).
> 4. Let rnum be ? ToNumeric(rval).

> (...do calculations on lnum and rnum)

If the value can't be converted to a sensible number - for example, `'a'` - then you'll get `NaN` as a result, but it doesn't throw an error.

`["155"]` turns into the number `155` because, when `["155"]` is converted to a primitive, it gets joined by `,`s: `["155"].join(',')` results in the string `'155'`. This primitive then gets converted into the number `155`.

Arrays with more than 1 item can't be converted to numbers, because a comma is not a valid numeric character:

```js
const arr = [1, 2];
console.log(
  String(arr),
  Number(arr)
);
```